# Can we save the name of a book we want to publish?

Tags: titles

I want to publish a book in India, with a particular name. Can I save the name for using it in future? Or if there is already one book published with the same name, can I use it again?

Comment: These answers may help you: [Can a title be copyrighted?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/can-a-title-be-copyrighted)  and [Title already taken](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/8150/can-a-title-be-copyrighted). There may be differences in India.

Answer (score 2):

"Copyright does not ordinarily protect titles by themselves or names, short word combinations, slogans, short phrases, methods, plots or factual information."  (https://copyright.gov.in/Documents/handbook.html) (Sometime while searching on amazon, you may have seen several books with the same title. This is not uncommon.) You can *trademark* a title if it is a distinctive title for a series of publications (example: *Harry Potter*). ([www.biswajitsarkar.com/blog](http://www.biswajitsarkar.com/blog))
You may not use the title of an existing book that is world-famous or nationally famous, at least not without permission. If you try, you may get a cease and desist letter from the publisher of that book.
You can register copyright for a titled manuscript that has not been published yet, as long as you can prove when the work was created and the fact that it is original, but this probably would not prevent someone else from using the same title in the meantime. There is copyright protection even if you do not register the copyright of an unpublished work, but unless you register it, you will not be able to defend any claim in a court of law. (https://copyright.gov.in/Documents/handbook.html)